# How to use CustomView in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view

In my application I create one custom view for show **TextView** and **FontAwesome**!
I write below codes, but not set values and just show default values!
**TextWithIcon class :**

```
class TextWithIcon @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0,
    defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyle, defStyleRes) {

    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_text_with_awesome, this, true)
        orientation = VERTICAL

        attrs?.let {
            val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.TextWithIcon)
            val title = resources.getText(
                typedArray.getResourceId(
                    R.styleable.TextWithIcon_customText,
                    R.string.app_name
                )
            )
            val icon = resources.getText(
                typedArray.getResourceId(
                    R.styleable.TextWithIcon_customIcon,
                    R.string.app_name
                )
            )

            val titleTxt = getChildAt(0) as TextView
            titleTxt.text = title
            Log.e("titleTxt",title.toString())
            //binding.iconTxt.text = "&#x$icon"

            typedArray.recycle()
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomViewLayout file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_20mdp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/darkJungleGreen"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_10font_mdp" />

    <com.myapp.utils.views.FontAwesome
        android:id="@+id/iconTxt"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_20mdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_20mdp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/beauBlue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_10font_mdp"
        app:fontPath="fonts/fontawesome_re.ttf" />

</merge>
```

And I used this class with code in XML :

```
        <com.myapp.TextWithIcon
            android:id="@+id/item1Title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10mdp"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_5mdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/ochre"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10font_mdp"
            app:customIcon="f007"
            app:customText="wegwergewrg"
            app:fontPath="fonts/iransans_bold.ttf"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/item1Line"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/item1Line" />
```

I set value with this code : `app:customText="wegwergewrg"`, but not show this and just show default value from

```
resources.getText(
                typedArray.getResourceId(
                    R.styleable.TextWithIcon_customText,
                    R.string.app_name
                )
            )
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want your styleable to look something like this:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="TextWithIcon">
        <attr name="customText" format="reference|string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

This definition will permit you to use text as well as a string resource id for "app:customText".

You can get the value from the attribute as follows:

```
class TestCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView(context, attrs) {

    init {
        val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextWithIcon)
        for (attr in 0 until a.indexCount) {
            when (a.getIndex(attr)) {
                R.styleable.TextWithIcon_customText -> {
                    text = a.getText(attr) ?: "Unknown text."
                }
            }
        }
        a.recycle()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, your answer to me. Just I have one question, in your code you use for loop. this code is good way for memory?

Comment: That's how the Android _View_ code works, so I think it's ok.